# Borrar un registro en c

Tags: c, estructuras

Tengo un programa que va registrando una serie de productos, parte de la funcionalidad que me falta es como borrar estos datos, no manejo un contador que solo pueda eliminar; por ahora tengo la función borrar  que solo es replica de la función consulta que no incluyo, que la idea es borrar el producto que solicites.

Inicialmente se debe crear un archivo si es que no existe, en el menú se hace con el número 6 que es la función crear que tendré que adjuntar aquí para que mi pregunta sea aceptada.

```
void crear()
{
    FILE *arch;
    arch=fopen("productos.dat","wb");
    if (arch==NULL)
        exit(1);
    fclose(arch);
}
```

Si podrían decirme si mi código es eficiente me serviría mucho, pensé en usar apuntadores, esos los use solo para registros no ligados a un archivo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int codigo;
    char descripcion[41];
    float precio;
    int cantidad;
    char fecha[10];
} tproducto;

void borrar()
{
    FILE *arch;
    arch=fopen("productos.dat","rb");
    if (arch==NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("Ingrese el codigo de producto a consultar: ");
    int cod;
    scanf("%i", &cod);
    tproducto producto;
    int existe=0;
    fread(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, arch);
    while(!feof(arch))
    {
        if (cod == producto.codigo)
        {
           printf("%i %s %0.2f\n", producto.codigo, producto.descripcion, producto.precio);
           existe=1;
           break;
        }
        fread(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, arch);
    }
    if (existe==0)
        printf("No existe un producto con dicho codigo\n");
    fclose(arch);
}

void cargar()
{
    FILE *arch;
    arch=fopen("productos.dat","ab");
    if (arch==NULL)
        exit(1);
    tproducto producto;
    system("cls");
    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ");
    scanf("%i",&producto.codigo);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ");
    gets(producto.descripcion);
    printf("Ingrese precio: ");
    scanf("%f",&producto.precio);
    printf("Cantidad de articulos: ");
    scanf("%i",&producto.cantidad);
    printf("Fecha de manufactura: ");
    scanf("%s",&producto.fecha);
    fwrite(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, arch);
    fclose(arch);
}

void listado()
{
    FILE *arch;
    arch=fopen("productos.dat","rb");
    if (arch==NULL)
        exit(1);
    tproducto producto;
    fread(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, arch);
    printf("\nCodigo\t Descripcion    \t Precio \tCantidad \t Fecha\n");
    while(!feof(arch))
    {
        printf("%-8i %-23s %0-8.2f  %9d \t\t %10s\n", producto.codigo, producto.descripcion, producto.precio, producto.cantidad, producto.fecha);
        fread(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, arch);
    }
    fclose(arch);
}

int main()
{
    int opcion;
    do {
        system("cls");
        printf("\t\tALMACEN\n");
        printf("\n1 - Agregar un articulo\n");
        printf("2 - Borrar un articulo\n");
        printf("3 - Listado completo de articulos\n");
        printf("4 - Consulta de un producto por su codigo.\n");
        printf("5 - Modificacion del precio de un producto. \n");
        printf("6 - Generar archivo. \n");
        printf("7 - Finalizar\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese su opcion: ");
        scanf("%i",&opcion);
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:cargar();
                   break;
            case 2:borrar();
                   break;
            case 3:listado();
                   break;
            case 4:consulta();
                   break;
            case 5:modificacion();
                   break;
            case 6:crear();
                break;
            case 7:exit(1);
                break;
        }
        printf("\nDesea realizar otra accion?: [1]Si  [2]No\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("\n%d",&opcion);

    } while (opcion == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

para eliminar un registro de un archivo, normalmente debes:

- crear un nuevo documento
- copiar los registros del documento viejo, excepto el que vas a eliminar
- eliminar el documento viejo
- renombrar el documento nuevo.

Puedes probar con este código:

```c
void borrar()
{
    FILE *arch;
    arch=fopen("productos.dat","rb");
    if (arch==NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("Ingrese el codigo de producto a eliminar: ");
    int cod;
    scanf("%i", &cod);
    tproducto producto;

    FILE *nuevo;
    nuevo=fopen("productos.tmp","ab");
    if (arch==NULL)
        exit(1);

    int existe=0;
    fread(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, arch);
    while(!feof(arch))
    {
        if (cod == producto.codigo)
        {
           printf("Eliminado %i %s %0.2f\n", producto.codigo, producto.descripcion, producto.precio);
           existe=1;
        }else{
            fwrite(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, nuevo);
        }
        fread(&producto, sizeof(tproducto), 1, arch);
    }
    if (existe==0)
        printf("No existe un producto con dicho codigo\n");
    fclose(arch);
    fclose(nuevo);
    
    remove("productos.dat");
    rename("productos.tmp", "productos.dat");
}
```

Comment: ohh muchas gracias, si vi esas 2 funciones, pero pensé que existía una mejor forma

Comment: Puedes aceptar la respuesta como válida si te parece que es la respuesta correcta para que otros en tu caso sepan que es la solución aceptada.